# when i input 90 it won't read the case 4, it reads and gave me the output of default

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace GradeEquivalent
{
    class Grades
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your grade: ");
            int grade;
            grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (grade)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69)
                        Console.WriteLine("Grade equivalent: D");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79)
                        Console.WriteLine("Grade equivalent: C");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89)
                        Console.WriteLine("Grade equivalent: B");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
                        Console.WriteLine("Grade equivalent: A");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid grade input.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i input 90 it won't read the case 4, it reads and gave me the output of default

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. How can `grade == 4` and at the same time `grade >= 90 && grade <= 100`? Is this Schrodinger's Grade? Until you look at it, you don't know if it's 4 or between 90 (incl.) and 100 (incl.)? If it's not clear `switch (grade) { case 4: /* code*/ }` is essentially saying `if (grade == 4) { /* code */ }` (in terms of functionality, at least).

Answer (score 3):

This is because you use `switch(grade)`. Case 4 will be entered only if the grade is equal 4, if the grade is 90, then it's not case 1,2,3,4, so it enters default.

You should delete the switch case and simply use if else.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are switching on `grade` which is not supposed to be 1, 2, 3 or 4 as indicated by the case labels. The case labels are not just a numbering of the cases, but must match the value you are switching on. But you can use a switch expression together with pattern matching. If you re-arrange the cases, this also simplifies the conditions, as the first matching condition will be taken:

```cs
string message = grade switch {
    < 60 or > 100 => "Invalid grade input.",
    < 70 => "Grade equivalent: D",
    < 80 => "Grade equivalent: C",
    < 90 => "Grade equivalent: B",
    _ => "Grade equivalent: A"
};
Console.WriteLine(message);
```